# Read a Liferay plugin's own liferay-plugin-package.properties from code in the plugin

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

How can a plugin's code get access to the properties set in its own liferay-plugin-package.properties file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DeployManagerUtil`

First import the following:

```java
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.DeployManagerUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.plugin.PluginPackage;
```

Second use it:

```java
PluginPackage pluginPackage = DeployManagerUtil.getInstalledPluginPackage("context-name");

String version = pluginPackage.getModuleId();
String pageURL = pluginPackage.getPageURL();
```

Comment: This answers the basic question of reading those properties.  But that api isn't complete.  e.g., getVersion() returns the version of the SDK (like 6.1.20), and leaves off what I really want, which is the incremental version (like 6.1.20.7).  The property module-incremental-version doesn't seem to be available. PluginPackageUtil might have something, but it doesn't seem to be available to plugins.

Comment: @npskirk, I'll reflect the current answer to reflect this but `getModuleId()` is the correct call. However, it appears to be concatenated with other info.

Comment: Actually, after reviewing it further `getVersion()` should return `{sdk-version}.{module-incremental-version}`. If I get a chance, I'll see if I can debug what is going on here but if you put a breakpoint and inspect the `pluginPackage` variable, you should be able to find the correct value.

Comment: Nope.  None of the properties in pluginPackage provide this information.  getModuleId returns a '/' separated string of aritfactId, groupId, pluginVersion and archive type.  The pluginVersion field is the same as you get for getVersion

Comment: It's be nice if you could add some examples of how to obtain the context name. In my case I had the `portletConfig`, so I obtained the context name like so: `portletConfig.getPortletContext().getPortletContextName()`.